# How to update deep nested state in React

Tags: reactjs, date, nested, state

```
[
{  
year:2022, 
month:"jan",
days: [
            { day: 1, isCompleted: false },
            { day: 2, isCompleted: false },
            // ... other days
      ]
},
{  
year:2022, 
month:"feb",
days: [
            { day: 1, isCompleted: false },
            { day: 2, isCompleted: false },
            // ... other days
      ]
},
// ... other months
]
```

My state value are like that. I render my all days and if i click specific day, i want to update it property of isCompleted to true. How can i update it.

I cannot figure out how to update nested state

Comment: it's impossible to answer this question without knowing what kind of state management solution you are using. useState, redux, something else?

Comment: Do i need state management? The state data is hard coded or comes from the database. I think i don't need state management for this bcz the code is flowing parent to child.

Comment: you say you're updating the state, but where is it that you're updating it?

Comment: I just showing state data. My point is to update isCompleted property inside days array. You miss my instruction i given i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for the year, month and day. Then just set `isCompleted` value to `true`. It might be a bit complicated, because when setting a state you must not modify the state itself.

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [datesState, setDatesState] = useState([...]);

  const onSelectDate = (inputDate) => {
    const inputDateDay = inputDate.getDate();
    const inputDateMonth = inputDate.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short" }).toLowerCase();
    const inputDateYear = inputDate.getFullYear();

    setDatesState((prev) => {
      const matchingYearAndMonthIndex = datesState.findIndex((date) => date.year === inputDateYear && date.month === inputDateMonth);

      if (matchingYearAndMonthIndex === -1) {
        return prev;
      }

      const matchingDayIndex = prev[matchingYearAndMonthIndex].findIndex((date) => date.day === inputDateDay);

      if (matchingDayIndex === -1) {
        return prev;
      }

      const prevCopy = [...prev];
      const yearAndMonthCopy = { ...prev[matchingYearAndMonthIndex] };
      const daysCopy = [ ...yearAndMonthCopy.days ];

      daysCopy[matchingDayIndex].isCompleted = true;
      yearAndMonthCopy.days = daysCopy;
      prevCopy[matchingYearAndMonthIndex] = yearAndMonthCopy;

      return prevCopy;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Too complicated for me. How can I train to logical thinking something like that. Any suggestion.

Comment: @Amos If you read it carefully, there is nothing complicated. Think of it like modifying the required key to `true` value, but also making sure that we don't modify the original state, previous one.

Comment: After figure it out for 2 hours. It make sense. I really appreciate for clear and concise answer.

Comment: @Amos Great, you should mark it as an answer

Comment: Sorry, i am new here. Also, i have no idea how to mention!